# Java Generics: What is the benefit of using wildcards here?

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-parameter, bounded-wildcard

The [Collections.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#fill(java.util.List,T)) method has the following header:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)
```

Why is the wildcard necessary? The following header seems to work just as well:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<T> list, T obj)
```

I cannot see a reason why the wildcard is needed; code such as the following works with the second header as well as the first:

```
List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
Integer i = 43;
fill(nums, i); //fill method written using second header
```

My question is: **For what specific call of `fill` would the first header work but not the second? And if there is no such call, why include the wildcard?** In this case, the wildcard does not make the method more concise nor add to readability (in my opinion).

Comment: In the first case, `T` is inferred to be `Integer` (with the wildcard), whereas it's inferred to be `Number` in the second case (without the wildcard). Not positive when that would make a practical difference, but there is a difference.

Comment: I suspect there's something in the type inference rules that makes the signature with a wildcard work in some cases where the signature without a wildcard fails. An example would probably need to involve type inference in the arguments to `fill`.

Comment: My best guess is that this notation clarifies or suggests that you can use fill on superclass objects in the list with those of type T, which you might not know if you had the second method signature, even though both seem to be the same practically

Comment: I think, the author just followed the PECS rule like with other methods, without considering that for this specific method, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really good question and the simple answer was guessed already:

> For the current version of the `fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)` there is no
> such input that would be rejected given the signature is changed to `fill(List<T> list, T obj)`, so there is no benefit and the devs are likely followed the PECS principle

The above statement derives from the principle that: if there is a such type `X` so that
`X` is a supertype of `T` then `List<X>` is a supertype of `List<? super T>` because of type contravariance.
Since we can always find such `X` (at the worst case it's the `Object` class) - the compiler can infer a suitable `List<X>` argument type given either form of `fill`.

So, knowing that fact we can interfere with the compiler and infer the type ourselves using "type witness" so the code breaks:

```
List<Object> target = new ArrayList<>();
//Compiles OK as we can represent List<Object> as List<? super Integer> and it fits
Collections.<Integer>fill(target, 1);

//Compilation error as List<Object> is invariant to List<Integer> and not a valid substitute
Collections.<Integer>fillNew(target, 1);
```

This is all of course purely theoretical and nobody in their right mind would use the type argument there.

**HOWEVER**

While answering the question "*What is the benefit of using wildcards here?*" we yet considered only one side of the equation - us, consumers of the method and our experience but not library developers.

Hence this question is somewhat similar to why `Collections.enumeration(final Collection<T> c)` is declared the way it is and not `enumeration(Collection<T> c)` as `final` seems superfluous for the end-user.

We can speculate here about the real intention, but I can give a few subjective reasons:

1. First: using `List<? super T>` (as well as `final` for `enumeration`) immediately disambiguates the code that tiny bit more and for the `<? super T>` specifically - it useful to show that only partial knowledge about the
   type parameter is required and the `list` cannot be used to produce values of T, but only to consume them.
   Quote:

> Wildcards are useful in situations where only partial knowledge about the type parameter is required.
> *[JLS 4.5.1. Type Arguments of Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)*

2. Second: it gives some freedom to the library owners to improve/update the method without breaking backward compatibility while conforming to the existing constraints.

---

Now let's try make up some hypothetical "improvements" to see what I mean (I'll call the form of `fill` that uses `List<T>` as `fillNew`):

#1 The decision is to make method to return the `obj` value (used to fill up the list) back:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)
//becomes ↓↓↓
public static <T> T fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)
```

The updated method would work just fine for `fill` signature, but for `fillNew` - the inferred return type now isn't that obvious:

```
List<Number> target = new ArrayList<>();
Long val = fill(target, 1L); //<<Here Long is the most specific type that fits both arguments
//Compilation error
Long val = fillNew(target, 1L); //<<Here Number is, so it cannot be assigned back

//More exotic case:
Integer val = fill(asList(true), 0); //val is Integer as expected
Comparable<?> val = fillNew(asList(true), 0); //val is now Comparable<?> as the most specific type
```

#2 The decision to add an overloaded version of `fill` that is 10x more performant in cases when `T` is `Comparable<T>`:

```
/* Extremely performant 10x version */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void fill(List<? super T> list, T value)
/* Normal version */
public static void fill(List<? super T> list, T value)

List<Number> target = new ArrayList<>();
fill(target, 1);  //<<< Here the more performant version is used as T inferred to Integer and it implements Comparable<Integer>
fillNew(target, 1); //<< Still uses the slow version just because T is inferred to Number which is not Comparable
```

To sum up - the current signature of `fill` is more flexible/descriptive in my opinion for all parties (developers and library designers)

Answer (score -1):

For your example, the reason it 'works' with your basic `<T>` signature, is that an Integer is also a Number. The only 'T' that works is `T = Number`, and then the whole thing just works out.

In this case, the expression you have for the `T obj` parameter is a reified type: You have an `Integer`. You could have a `T` instead. Perhaps you have this:

```
class AtomicReference<T> {
  // The actual impl of j.u.concurrent.AtomicReference...
  // but with this one additional method:

  public void fillIntoList(List<? super T> list) {
    T currentValue = get();
    Collections.fill(list, currentValue);
  }
}
```

I may perhaps want to write something like this:

```
AtomicReference<String> ref = new AtomicReference<String>("hello");
List<CharSequence> texts = new ArrayList<>();

...

ref.fillIntoList(texts);
```

If my hypothetical `fillIntoList` method simply had `List<T>` in the signature that wouldn't compile. Fortunately it does, so the code does compile. Had the `Collections.fill` method not done the `<? super T>` thing, the invocation of the `Collections.fill` method in my `fillIntoList` method would have failed.

It's highly exotic for any of this to come up. But it can come up. `List<? super T>` is the strictly superior signature here - it can do everything `List<T>` does, and more, and it is also semantically correct: Of course I can fill a list-of-foos by writing into every slot a ref to something that I know for sure is a bar, if bar is a child of foo.

Comment: What happens at T currentValue = get()?

Comment: [When I try it](https://ideone.com/iinaLQ), `fillIntoList` compiles just fine even with a `fill` with the signature proposed in the question.

Comment: `fillIntoList` needs a wildcard, but that's because `T` is pinned down separately from the type of `list`. `Collections.fill` doesn't need a wildcard for this example to work.

Answer (score -3):

That is because the inheritance is useful is some cases.

For example, if you have the following class structure:

```
public class Parent {
  //some code
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  //some another code
}
```

You could use the first method writing:

```
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
Parent otherParentObject = new Parent(); //after this line, set the values for the class
List<Parent> outParentList = new ArrayList<>();
fill(children, otherParentObject); //fill method using first signature;
```

Comment: But wouldn't you get the same result if it were not ? super T in the method signature?

Comment: @RichardKYu is not the same: 
If you use only the second signature, using my example:
fill(outParentList, otherParentObject); //this compile
fill(children, otherParentObject); //this fails in compilation time

Comment: `fill(children, otherParentObject);` is supposed to fail. You're not allowed to put a `Parent` in a `List<Child>`.

Comment: It fails with either the actual `Collections.fill` signature or the signature proposed in the question.

Comment: Fails with the signature proposed in the question.